# Create Hash with strings or symbols as keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I saw a ruby script that defines an array of hashes like this:

```
boxes = [
  { :name => "playground",    :ip => "19" },
  { :name => "elkstack",      :ip => "22" },
  { :name => "audit",         :ip => "23" }
]
```

I'm not quite sure if this is the right way to define hashes. I thought you'd rather define this array of hashes like this:

```
boxes = [
  { "name" => "playground",    "ip" => "19" },
  { "name" => "elkstack",      "ip" => "22" },
  { "name" => "audit",         "ip" => "23" }
]
```

Could you tell which one is the right way to define hashes? Does it have side effects you'd maybe want to avoid or provoke to define those hash members as symbols?

Comment: The key for a ruby Hash can be of any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways are correct. In the first case, the hash key will be symbols, in the second case, they will be strings.

Generally speaking, it's common to use symbols as hash keys as they are slightly more efficient since when you type the same symbol more than once, it just gets allocated once, conversely if you type the same string N times, it will be allocated N times.

In fact, there is even a shortcut for it.

```
boxes = [
   { name: "playground",    ip: "19" },
   { name: "elkstack",      ip: "22" },
   { name: "audit",         ip: "23" }
]
```

Comment: Nowadays that isn't correct anymore with frozen/deduped strings. And also since 2.1 there is only one `"name"` and one `"ip"` ([demo](https://eval.in/private/8829e56cd45bc8)).

Comment: so with deduped strings, the memory problem of using multiple strings of the same value should not be a problem anymore. Isn't it a disadvantage to use symbols then? I've read that symbols, that weren't created dynamically, won't get garbage collected. Wouldn't the symbol approach be a memory leak?

Comment: In this case both freezing and deduplication are done automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer, simone carletti. and also thanks for the handy shortcut. i'll use it next time. i'd still be interested in an answer to my other comment if you could also help me with that: with deduped strings and therefore no memory problem when using strings, isn't it bad to use symbols then? afaik they aren't garbage collected, which would result in memory only beeing freed when the program ends, wouldn't it?